# Artifactory npm mirror does not serve package, which got removed from global registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, artifactory

In our company we use Artifactory to cache npm artifacts from the global registry at https://registry.npmjs.org/ . The intention is that our builds do not break if the global registry is down or packages are removed.
However it does not work:
We have a fixed dependency in our project's package.json to gulp-sourcemap@2.2.1. This package is no more available in the global registry since the weekend. Since today we get this error, when we run "npm install":

```
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: gulp-sourcemaps@2.2.1
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.0, 2.1.1, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-alpha, 1.9.3, 1.9.2, 1.9.0, 1.8.1, 1.7.3, 1.7.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.0, 1.2.8, 1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 0.4.6, 0.4.5, 0.4.4, 0.4.3, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.0
```

What makes us wonder is that the package is still available in the artifactory cache and also in the local caches on our dev servers.

Why does Artifactory not serve the package? Or why is npm not satisfied by getting the artifact from a local cache? Is there a way to change this behavior?

Our local registry is configured by setting the registry in the projects .npmrc file:

```
registry = <url_to_artifactory_cache>
```

we use artifactory version 3.8.0, node 6.9.4, npm 3.10.10

Comment: Seems that gulp-sourcemaps@2.2.1 is available again.
But the question remains

Comment: Is the configured registry a remote Artifactory repository or a virtual one? you can copy the specific version to a local repository, aggregate it together with the remote repository in a virtual repository and use the virtual as the registry

Comment: We have a remote one.

Comment: I also found out what is causing the error. Npm always tries to fetch the metadata, likely to evaluate the version to fetch if you use ranges as it is common. But it does that also if you use a fixed version and there's no way to suppress this. And the fetchMetadata call is routed to the global registry.
There is a caching logic in place if the global registry is down, but that was not the problem here. Seems like the issue is more that the metadata from the global registry was used, but not enriched with the information about the artifacts in the Artifactory cache.